# Make google chrome bookmark to a button on a page

Tags: browser, bookmarks

There is a webpage that I frequently use at work, where I go to the page and then click on a button on the page.  What I would like is to have a bookmark which takes me directly to the destination of the button.

If I inspect element on the button, I get this:

```
<a href="#" id="new" onclick="Rally.nav.Manager.create('defect', {iteration: 'u'});return false;">New Defect.../a>"
```

Is there a way I can bookmark this page and then have my browser automatically perform that onclick action as a command, thus taking me directly to the button destination?

Answer (score 1):

If the page navigates when you click the link we may be able to help more if you give us a link to the page. Besides that...

I don't think you can access the page post-load from a script that you run pre-navigation because it would violate the same origin policy. The easiest way would probably be to install the Tampermonkey plugin for chrome. To start, create a new user script and add the page with the button as an "Included Page".

The script could be pretty simple since the button has an ID.

```
document.getElementById('new').click();
```

If the page uses jQuery you can simplify it to

```
$("#new").click();
```

Depending on how the content is created the button may not exist on page load in which case you could use a timeout or jQueries .ready method on the document to give the page time to finish loading.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('new').click();
}, 1000); //milliseconds to wait, can be adjusted
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#new").click();
});
```